# Logcat shows-The real object has been deleted

Tags: android, facebook

I am doing 'Facebook integration on Android' and post status on facebook wall.I had followed "http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-use-facebook-sdk-to-post-status-from-android". But when i press button to post,it is getting stucked in emulator.In logcat its shown as "The real object has been deleted".Can u pls tell me what is the reason.Thanks

Comment: put some more information from the logcat

Answer (score 0):

did you get this error in real device too?
Exceptions like that are often an emulator problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file do you have  `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"` ?

If so, try to remove that line and then run it again.